# Sending and receiving files on socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I am sending files to remote Android client from java server. I write the bytes using outputstream. On reading these bytes read() method keep trying to read bytes after the stream is ended. if I close the `outputstream` on server-side, read operation work fines. But I have to write file on the same socket again so can't close output stream any solution?

**NOTE: MY CODE WORKS FINE FOR SHARING SINGLE FILE**

**CODE FOR WRITING FILE**

```
public static void writefile(String IP, String filepath, int port, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ByteFileConversion bfc = new ByteFileConversion();
    byte[] file = bfc.FileToByteConversion(filepath);

    out.write(file, 0, file.length);
    out.close(); // i donot want to close this and how can I tell reading side that stream is ended.
    System.out.println("WRITTEN");
}
```

Here Am I reading the file on Android :

```
public Bitmap fileReceived(InputStream is) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "a.png";
    String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
    //  System.out.println(imageInSD);
    if (is != null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        OutputStream bos = null;
        try {

            bos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);

            byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            int index = 0;
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);


            while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) > 0) {
                index = bytesRead + index;
                bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);

                //  index = index+ bytesRead;

                System.out.println("Loop" + aByte + "    byte read are " + bytesRead + "whree  index =" + index);

            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "out of loop");
            java.io.FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageInSD);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);

            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "saved");
            //  if (bitmap != null) 
            //       System.out.println("bitmap is    "+ bitmap.toString());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling      
            //      Log.i("IMSERVICE", "exception ");
            System.out.println("ex");
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Actually, I want to  reset `socket` connection

Thanks in advance

Comment: my code correctly write and read file. I want to use outputsream again which is close to write another file. But as outputstream is close so i cannot do that. If i donot close outputstream the read operation on other side stuck on keep reading

Comment: @RodAlgonquin There is no way in TCP to send and receive a single packet of data. It is a byte stream. You have to add metadata of your own.

Comment: @EJP I see but that was not really his problem, he wants his output to be open as I suggested below but I dont know why they downvoted it.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin That is exactly his problem. He needs to stop reading after the end of the first file, and at present he has no way of telling the end of the file other than end of stream of the sockets. See my answer fpr solution. Just moving the blocking behaviour into a separate thread doesn't address the issue at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to:

1. Send the length of the file ahead of the file. You can use `DataOutputStream.writeLong()` for that, and `DataInputStream.readLong()` at the receiver.
2. Read exactly that many bytes from the stream at the receiver:

   ```
   while (total < length && (count = in.read(buffer, 0, length-total > buffer.length ? buffer.length : (int)(length-total))) > 0)
   {
       out.write(buffer, 0, count);
       total += count;
   }
   ```

E&OE

> Actually I want to reset socket connection

Actually you don't want to do any such thing.

Comment: I used DataOutputStream.writelong()

Answer (score -1):

> If i donot close outputstream the read operation on other side stuck on keep reading

That is because the client socket's `InputStream` is still waiting for the server to send some packets of data thus blocking your Main Thread.

Solution:

You can put each of your sending(`OutputStream`) and reading(`InputStream`) of packets of data from the socket to a Thread to prevent blocking your main thread when reading and sending.

Create a thread that reads the `InputStream` and another one for the `OutputStream`

Side note:

Don't try to close your outputStream that it cant be reopened again as the documentation is saying:

Closing the returned OutputStream will close the associated socket.

The general contract of close is that it closes the output stream. A closed stream cannot perform output operations and cannot be reopened.

Comment: I put output stream in  thread but result is same. closing output stream in thread closes socket :(